# nth child selector css

Tags: html, css

I have a div pattern here , this pattern have minimum 9 number of `<div class="abc">` and this pattern is repeating . The background color of div is given

```
    1 white
    2 green
    3 white
    4 green
    5 white
    6 green
    7 green
    8 white
    9 green
```

so to make it work I write following css

```
  $(".test:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color","green");
  $(".test:nth-child(even)").css("background-color","green");
  $(".test:nth-child(7n)").css("background-color","green");
  $(".test:nth-child(8n)").css("background-color","white");
  $(".test:nth-child(9n)").css("background-color","green");
```

Now everything work , but the problem is that when number of divs comes more than 9 then the 10th div is starting from background green but it need to be white .

**for example if there is 18 div then**

```
    1  white
    2  green
    3  white
    4  green
    5  white
    6  green
    7  green
    8  white
    9  green
    10 white
    11 green
    12 white
    13 green
    14 white
    15 green
    16 green
    17 white
    18 green
```

please suggest good formula to solve this

Comment: Please provide the HTML.

Comment: Why are six and seven both green? Is that a mistake or is it the expected pattern?

Comment: Also red != green.

Comment: create a demo with what you tried sofar?

Comment: @Harry that is expected pattern

Comment: @Paulie_D  changed . Please see edited question

Comment: So is 7 just an anomaly or will that be extended to other elements? This doesn't look like a pattern to me at all.

Comment: this is the expected pattern . upto 6 everything is ordered . From 7 to 9 everything is reverse order .then again pattern start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i hope this one is help u
use this one using css

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

**css:**

```
  .test{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin:10px;
  }
  .test:nth-child(9n+1){background-color:white;}
  .test:nth-child(9n+2){background-color:green;}
  .test:nth-child(9n+3){background-color:white;}
  .test:nth-child(9n+4){background-color:green;}
  .test:nth-child(9n+5){background-color:white;}
  .test:nth-child(9n+6){background-color:green;}
  .test:nth-child(9n+7){background-color:green;}
  .test:nth-child(9n+8){background-color:white;}
  .test:nth-child(9n+9){background-color:green;}
```

see jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/db0eedrL/2/

Comment: thank you . but this is wrong . Please see the question.

Comment: ok thanks .pls vote to my ans and let me know what do you want exactly.

Comment: thanks for vote and above comments jsfiddle is your proper answer

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you want to inverse pattern after 7 (which should be white but you want it green)

```css
.test {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Every other child starting at 1 */
.test:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background-color: white;
}

/* Every other child starting at 2 */
.test:nth-child(2n + 2) {
  background-color: green;
}

/* Every other child starting at 7 */
.test:nth-child(2n + 7) {
  background-color: green;
}

/* Every other child starting at 8 */
.test:nth-child(2n + 8) {
  background-color: white;
}

/* Every other child starting at 16 */
.test:nth-child(2n + 16) {
  background-color: green;
}

/* Every other child starting at 17 */
.test:nth-child(2n + 17) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">1 white</div>
<div class="test">2 green</div>
<div class="test">3 white</div>
<div class="test">4 green</div>
<div class="test">5 white</div>
<div class="test">6 green</div>
<div class="test">7 green</div>
<div class="test">8 white</div>
<div class="test">9 green</div>
<div class="test">10 white</div>
<div class="test">11 green</div>
<div class="test">12 white</div>
<div class="test">13 green</div>
<div class="test">14 white</div>
<div class="test">15 green</div>
<div class="test">16 green</div>
<div class="test">17 white</div>
<div class="test">18 green</div>
<div class="test">19 white</div>
<div class="test">20 green</div>
<div class="test">21 white</div>
<div class="test">22 green</div>
<div class="test">23 white</div>
<div class="test">24 green</div>
<div class="test">25 white</div>
<div class="test">26 green</div>
```

I've commented the code to make it easier to understand

I've used CSS but you can set this with Jquery if you like (as you are currently)

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry friend. There is an error . up to 18 it is ok .but after that the pattern is not repeating .

Comment: @Manik what are you expecting it to do? I've gone up to 26 in my example (I've updated it) and it's working as I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child` works without "n" that it is next to number (in this case).