# How do i style two same class divs differently?

Tags: css, css-selectors

So basically I've got a setup that spits out the code in the following fashion..

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="subparent">
      <div class="TARGETCLASS"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="subparent">
      <div class="TARGETCLASS"></div>
   </div>
</div> //close for the parent class
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to style "TARGETCLASS" that comes above one way and the "TARGETCLASS" that comes second in another way. I tried n-th child, but unable to achieve the result I'm looking for. There's no way to add additional classes or ID to the existing "TARGETCLASS" class. Otherwise I wouldn't be posting this question :)

Also, the "subparent" class also is same. for both the targetclass classes. That's the issue
Thanks in advance for taking your time to answer this question for me.

Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nth child selctor css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400955/nth-child-selctor-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use nth-of-type selector like so:

```
.parent{}
.parent > .subparent {}  //targets both subparents
.parent > .subparent:nth-of-type(2) {} //targets the second subparent
.parent > .subparent:nth-of-type(2) > .TARGETCLASS{} //targets the child of the  second subparent
```

The nth-of-type() selector enables you to style a specific element amongst a series, in this case we targeted the second .subparent then specified the child we needed.
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got some mal-formed tags in your html. And `nth-child` should work just fine. Also, make sure you place the `nth-child` selector on the `subparent` class, and not `TARGETCLASS`. It's common to mis-place the child selector. Try this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="subparent">
    <div class="TARGETCLASS">
      first-child
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subparent">
    <div class="TARGETCLASS">
      second-child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.parent .subparent .TARGETCLASS {
  background-color:#f00;
}
.parent .subparent:nth-child(1) .TARGETCLASS {
  background-color:#0f0;
}
</style>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ejxokuj/

Answer (score 0):

It seems, it is working by the nth child.
it is about how childrens are called. Not like "Ask parent to find nth child, but ask child, how far is he from parent"

```css
.parent .subparent:nth-child(1) {background: #FEE; color:RED;}
.parent .subparent:nth-child(2) {background: #EEF; color:blue;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="subparent">
<div class="TARGETCLASS">aaa</div>
</div>
<div class="subparent">
<div class="TARGETCLASS">bbb</div>
</div>
//close for the parent class
</div>
```